# Db2: How to convert Unix / epoch time to timestamp?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, epoch, dashdb

I have a BIGINT value which represents a UNIX timestamp (epoch). How can I convert it to the built-in TIMESTAMP type?

As example, I want to turn 1611140400 into the related date and time. TIMESTAMP_FORMAT does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [datetime arithmetics](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-datetime-operations-durations) in Db2 and Db2 on Cloud. For Db2 on Cloud (which is running in UTC):

```
VALUES (TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01') + 1611140400 seconds)
```

Epoch is seconds since January 1st, 1970 GMT / UTC. Thus, adding your number as seconds to that date will give:

> 2021-01-20 11:00:00.0

If you are running in a different timezone, you need to take care of it, e.g.:

```
VALUES (TIMESTAMP(‘1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000’) + 1611140400 seconds + current timezone)
```

Comment: Unix epoch time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 *GMT*, so you need to account for this when doing the conversion to a local time stamp (unless you’re in GMT already): 

`VALUES TIMESTAMP(‘1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000’) + 1611140400 seconds + current timezone`

Comment: added it in, also that Db2 on Cloud is in UTC

Comment: I found I had to divide the BIGINT value by 1000, presumably in my case the BIGINT represents milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, and there is no option to add/subtract milliseconds.